# Display JSON with random Key AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a JSON JS Object. I need to dsiplay this data with ng-repeat. The problem is the base key for array is changing. i do i tackle this. this JSON will be nested ng-repeat

```
var JSON = {
        "DK-App": [{
            "_id": 1056,
            "thread_id": 328,
            "address": "DK-App",
            "date": 1507470152962,
            "date_sent": 1507470093000,
            "protocol": 0,
            "read": 0,
            "status": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "reply_path_present": 0,
            "locked": 0,
            "sub_id": 2,
            "phone_id": 1,
            "error_code": 0,
            "creator": "com.android.mms",
            "seen": 0,
            "priority": -1,
            "oppo_drafts": 1,
            "sim_id": -1,
            "oppo_mass": 0,
            "oppo_timer": 0,
            "oppo_groupaddress": "DK-App",
            "oppo_collected": 0,
            "oppo_sub_date": 1507470093000,
            "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "sync_state": 0,
            "oppo_sms_type": 0,
            "$$hashKey": "object:4"
        }, {
            "_id": 1028,
            "thread_id": 328,
            "address": "DK-App",
            "date": 1507360655265,
            "date_sent": 1507360594000,
            "protocol": 0,
            "read": 0,
            "status": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "reply_path_present": 0,
            "locked": 0,
            "sub_id": 2,
            "phone_id": 1,
            "error_code": 0,
            "creator": "com.android.mms",
            "seen": 1,
            "priority": -1,
            "oppo_drafts": 1,
            "sim_id": -1,
            "oppo_mass": 0,
            "oppo_timer": 0,
            "oppo_groupaddress": "DK-App",
            "oppo_collected": 0,
            "oppo_sub_date": 1507360594000,
            "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "sync_state": 0,
            "oppo_sms_type": 0,
            "$$hashKey": "object:27"
        }, {
            "_id": 985,
            "thread_id": 328,
            "address": "DK-App",
            "date": 1507198047122,
            "date_sent": 1507197980000,
            "protocol": 0,
            "read": 0,
            "status": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "reply_path_present": 0,
            "locked": 0,
            "sub_id": 2,
            "phone_id": 1,
            "error_code": 0,
            "creator": "com.android.mms",
            "seen": 1,
            "priority": -1,
            "oppo_drafts": 1,
            "sim_id": -1,
            "oppo_mass": 0,
            "oppo_timer": 0,
            "oppo_groupaddress": "DK-App",
            "oppo_collected": 0,
            "oppo_sub_date": 1507197980000,
            "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "sync_state": 0,
            "oppo_sms_type": 0,
            "$$hashKey": "object:45"
        }, {
            "_id": 977,
            "thread_id": 328,
            "address": "DK-App",
            "date": 1507179236636,
            "date_sent": 0,
            "read": 0,
            "status": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "locked": 0,
            "sub_id": 2,
            "phone_id": 1,
            "error_code": 0,
            "creator": "com.android.mms",
            "seen": 1,
            "priority": -1,
            "oppo_drafts": 1,
            "sim_id": -1,
            "oppo_mass": 0,
            "oppo_timer": 0,
            "oppo_collected": 0,
            "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "sync_state": 0,
            "oppo_sms_type": 0,
            "$$hashKey": "object:48"
        }],
        "BZ-FPANDA": [{
            "_id": 1055,
            "thread_id": 96,
            "address": "BZ-FPANDA",
            "date": 1507469661223,
            "date_sent": 1507469657000,
            "protocol": 0,
            "read": 0,
            "status": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "reply_path_present": 0,
            "locked": 0,
            "sub_id": 1,
            "phone_id": 0,
            "error_code": 0,
            "creator": "com.android.mms",
            "seen": 0,
            "priority": -1,
            "oppo_drafts": 1,
            "sim_id": -1,
            "oppo_mass": 0,
            "oppo_timer": 0,
            "oppo_groupaddress": "BZ-FPANDA",
            "oppo_collected": 0,
            "oppo_sub_date": 1507469657000,
            "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "sync_state": 0,
            "oppo_sms_type": 0,
            "$$hashKey": "object:5"
        }, {
            "_id": 930,
            "thread_id": 96,
            "address": "BZ-FPANDA",
            "date": 1506925028930,
            "date_sent": 1506925025000,
            "protocol": 0,
            "read": 0,
            "status": -1,
            "type": 1,
            "reply_path_present": 0,
            "locked": 0,
            "sub_id": 1,
            "phone_id": 0,
            "error_code": 0,
            "creator": "com.android.mms",
            "seen": 1,
            "priority": -1,
            "oppo_drafts": 1,
            "sim_id": -1,
            "oppo_mass": 0,
            "oppo_timer": 0,
            "oppo_groupaddress": "BZ-FPANDA",
            "oppo_collected": 0,
            "oppo_sub_date": 1506925025000,
            "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "sync_state": 0,
            "oppo_sms_type": 0,
            "$$hashKey": "object:56"
        }]
    }
```

this JSON need to create list for each Array. however each Key for an Array is different. the ng-repeat is not working with

```
ng-repeat="j in JSON"
```

Before this i tried to normalize this Array list by pushing common n based on Key only

```
var result = {};
                    data.forEach(function(item) {
                      if (!result[item.address]) 
                        result[item.address] = [item];
                      else
                        result[item.address].push(item);
                    });
```

Now i get a JSON with "KEYS" containing an Array. Original JSON Lools Like This

I have tried to push common object based on key `address`.
I need to access "DK-App" and "BZ-FPANDA" in JSON variable and need to iterate the Array inside both "DK-APP" and "BZ-FPANDA". Please note both these "DK-APP" and "BZ-FPANDA" comes programnatically from backend and there is huge list like this. The problem statement is how how i get hold of array using JS so that i can iterate over it

Comment: I need to access "DK-App" and "BZ-FPANDA" in JSON variable and need to iterate the Array inside both "DK-APP" and "BZ-FPANDA". Please note both these "DK-APP" and "BZ-FPANDA" comes programnatically from backend and there is huge list like this. The problem statement is how how i get hold of array using JS so that i can iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

With normalized data

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.data">
  Creator of {{ item._id }} is {{ item.creator }}
</div>
```

Without unnormalized data

```
<div ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.JSON">
   <div  ng-repeat="item in data">
      Creator of {{ item._id }} is {{ item.creator }}
  </div>
</div>
```

If your problem persists, please create a plunker example.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is nested one level, you can write a nested loop in your template to extract each item inside of the object.

```js
var JSONdata = {
  "DK-App": [{
    "_id": 1056,
    "thread_id": 328,
    "address": "DK-App",
    "date": 1507470152962,
    "date_sent": 1507470093000,
    "protocol": 0,
    "read": 0,
    "status": -1,
    "type": 1,
    "reply_path_present": 0,
    "locked": 0,
    "sub_id": 2,
    "phone_id": 1,
    "error_code": 0,
    "creator": "com.android.mms",
    "seen": 0,
    "priority": -1,
    "oppo_drafts": 1,
    "sim_id": -1,
    "oppo_mass": 0,
    "oppo_timer": 0,
    "oppo_groupaddress": "DK-App",
    "oppo_collected": 0,
    "oppo_sub_date": 1507470093000,
    "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "sync_state": 0,
    "oppo_sms_type": 0,
    "$$hashKey": "object:4"
  }, {
    "_id": 1028,
    "thread_id": 328,
    "address": "DK-App",
    "date": 1507360655265,
    "date_sent": 1507360594000,
    "protocol": 0,
    "read": 0,
    "status": -1,
    "type": 1,
    "reply_path_present": 0,
    "locked": 0,
    "sub_id": 2,
    "phone_id": 1,
    "error_code": 0,
    "creator": "com.android.mms",
    "seen": 1,
    "priority": -1,
    "oppo_drafts": 1,
    "sim_id": -1,
    "oppo_mass": 0,
    "oppo_timer": 0,
    "oppo_groupaddress": "DK-App",
    "oppo_collected": 0,
    "oppo_sub_date": 1507360594000,
    "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "sync_state": 0,
    "oppo_sms_type": 0,
    "$$hashKey": "object:27"
  }, {
    "_id": 985,
    "thread_id": 328,
    "address": "DK-App",
    "date": 1507198047122,
    "date_sent": 1507197980000,
    "protocol": 0,
    "read": 0,
    "status": -1,
    "type": 1,
    "reply_path_present": 0,
    "locked": 0,
    "sub_id": 2,
    "phone_id": 1,
    "error_code": 0,
    "creator": "com.android.mms",
    "seen": 1,
    "priority": -1,
    "oppo_drafts": 1,
    "sim_id": -1,
    "oppo_mass": 0,
    "oppo_timer": 0,
    "oppo_groupaddress": "DK-App",
    "oppo_collected": 0,
    "oppo_sub_date": 1507197980000,
    "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "sync_state": 0,
    "oppo_sms_type": 0,
    "$$hashKey": "object:45"
  }, {
    "_id": 977,
    "thread_id": 328,
    "address": "DK-App",
    "date": 1507179236636,
    "date_sent": 0,
    "read": 0,
    "status": -1,
    "type": 1,
    "locked": 0,
    "sub_id": 2,
    "phone_id": 1,
    "error_code": 0,
    "creator": "com.android.mms",
    "seen": 1,
    "priority": -1,
    "oppo_drafts": 1,
    "sim_id": -1,
    "oppo_mass": 0,
    "oppo_timer": 0,
    "oppo_collected": 0,
    "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "sync_state": 0,
    "oppo_sms_type": 0,
    "$$hashKey": "object:48"
  }],
  "BZ-FPANDA": [{
    "_id": 1055,
    "thread_id": 96,
    "address": "BZ-FPANDA",
    "date": 1507469661223,
    "date_sent": 1507469657000,
    "protocol": 0,
    "read": 0,
    "status": -1,
    "type": 1,
    "reply_path_present": 0,
    "locked": 0,
    "sub_id": 1,
    "phone_id": 0,
    "error_code": 0,
    "creator": "com.android.mms",
    "seen": 0,
    "priority": -1,
    "oppo_drafts": 1,
    "sim_id": -1,
    "oppo_mass": 0,
    "oppo_timer": 0,
    "oppo_groupaddress": "BZ-FPANDA",
    "oppo_collected": 0,
    "oppo_sub_date": 1507469657000,
    "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "sync_state": 0,
    "oppo_sms_type": 0,
    "$$hashKey": "object:5"
  }, {
    "_id": 930,
    "thread_id": 96,
    "address": "BZ-FPANDA",
    "date": 1506925028930,
    "date_sent": 1506925025000,
    "protocol": 0,
    "read": 0,
    "status": -1,
    "type": 1,
    "reply_path_present": 0,
    "locked": 0,
    "sub_id": 1,
    "phone_id": 0,
    "error_code": 0,
    "creator": "com.android.mms",
    "seen": 1,
    "priority": -1,
    "oppo_drafts": 1,
    "sim_id": -1,
    "oppo_mass": 0,
    "oppo_timer": 0,
    "oppo_groupaddress": "BZ-FPANDA",
    "oppo_collected": 0,
    "oppo_sub_date": 1506925025000,
    "oppo_service_message_sms_type": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "sync_state": 0,
    "oppo_sms_type": 0,
    "$$hashKey": "object:56"
  }]
}

var module = angular.module("myApp", []);

module.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.messages = JSONdata;
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="(address, messageList) in messages">
      <h3>{{address}}</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="message in messageList">
          <pre>{{message | json}}</pre>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what your expectations are you can either flatten the data or use nested `ng-repeat` where the outer repeat iterates the main object and the inner one iterates the inner arrays

Using nested repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, arr) in JSON">
   Key is: {{k}}
   <div  ng-repeat="item in arr">
      Item address is : {{item.address}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have to normalize JSOn by creating Array based on key (address). this will create a new JSON based on key address and would contain am Array with all values with matching address key field

Comment: Provide your expected results